# Finding the time dependent ket for a quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, time-evolution

I'm having troubles finding the time-dependent expression of a system using kets instead of wavefunctions. For example, let $\mid \psi(t=0)\rangle $ be the state of a system at the initial instant, expressed in terms of the eigenestates of the $\hat {L ^2}$ and $\hat L_z$ operators, $| l,m\rangle$:

$$
\mid \psi(t=0)\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}(|2,1\rangle+3| 1,-1\rangle)
$$

What my books suggests to do is to find it by computing this operation:

$$
|\psi(t)\rangle=\sum | j\rangle \langle j \mid \psi(0)\rangle e^{-i E_{j} t / \hbar}
$$

As far as I know, the $|j\rangle \langle j|$ term is the projection operator. However, is this operator included in the formula? What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Are the $|j\rangle$'s the energy eigenstates? Do you know what is meant by completeness relation? Do you know what the time evolution operator is for a time-independent Hamiltonian?

Comment: Not sure about the $|j\rangle$, and I didn't know about the completeness relation nor the time evolution operator. This problem is Example 9-21 of this chapter:

https://faculty.washington.edu/seattle/physics227/reading/reading-24-25.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The operator is called the resolution of unity:

$$ 1 = \sum_j|j\rangle\langle j| $$

So you can left multiply by it. $j$ is a label for the quantum numbers of the complete basis.

In your case,  $\langle j|\psi(0)\rangle$ is only non-zero if $l,m=2,1$ or $l,m=1,-1$ so the sum is reduced to:

$$ \sum_j|j\rangle\langle j|\psi(0)\rangle e^{iE_jt/\hbar}=
\frac 1 {\sqrt{10}}\big[
|2,1\rangle e^{iE_{2,1}t/\hbar} +3|1,-1\rangle e^{iE_{1,-1}t/\hbar}
\big]$$

so can see what it does: it picks out each basis state in $|\psi(0)\rangle$ and multiples it by the energy dependent phase-factor (which is the time evolution of that basis state), and then recombines them into a normalized state at $t$.

Of course, $E_{l,m}$ depends on the hamiltonian.

Comment: How do you know that the basis states $|l,m\rangle$ are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian? In other words, where do the factors $e^{-E_j t}$ come from?

Comment: l and m are good quantum numbers if the hamiltonian has rotational symmetry, which is implied b/c they are used.